# Javascript only allow numbers at end of text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this script which only allows <kbd>0-9</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> characters for negative numbers. However this does not prevent a user from entering <kbd>123-</kbd> for example and it causes errors. Is there a workaround for this? I prefer to stick to JavaScript as much as possible. But I am open to plugins if there is no other way.

It is working well by not allowing other characters such as letter. But I need to prevent users from entering <kbd>-</kbd> at the end or any other part aside from the start of the line.

```
function validate(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[0-9-]|\./;

    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: `/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/` I use this as a RegEx for numbers.

Comment: I tried both of those but I can't enter -

maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: var regex = /[0-9-]|\./; I'm replacing that part with var regex = /[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/

Comment: You wish to allow decimal numbers?

Comment: Integers and - only for negative values. But - must only be allowed at start. Not in the middle or end of the line

Comment: I think you can change your RegEx to `/^-?\d+$/`

Answer (score 1):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1phzy3ks/)

**JS**

```
// validates the key down event
function validate(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    // checks if it is a digit or first char is a -
    if (!/^-?\d+/.test(key)) {
        console.log(key);
        // stops event 100% if it isn't what you want
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();  
        evt.returnValue = false;
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Regex**

```
^-?\d+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Description**

```
/-?\d+/
^ assert position at start of the string
-? matches the character - literally
    Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\d+ match a digit [0-9]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Hmm I can't enter - even in first character. My char code for - is 189 maybe it's quite different?

Comment: @aozora you are correct, it is because of the keycode stuff...let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

if you like regexp you can try using this

```
(-|[0-9]?)[0-9]+
```

It means start is either - or a number. Then followed by only number

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your regex a little!

`var regex = /-?\d+`/

the ? means 0 or 1 and d+ will verify digits only.

Answer (score 0):

Matching only positive and negative integers can be done with the regex `/^-?\d+$/`.

**Explanation:**

`^` - start of string

`-?` - optional negative sign {greedy; 0-1}

`\d+` - one or more decimal digits, i.e. [0-9] {greedy; 1-infinity}

`$` - end of string

**Demo:**

```
> /^-?\d+$/.test('42')
true
> /^-?\d+$/.test('-42')
true
> /^-?\d+$/.test('42-')
false
> /^-?\d+$/.test('a42')
false
> /^-?\d+$/.test('42b')
false
```